# How to Gridview onClick go to various of screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, gridview, onclick

I am try to long days to set Grid view onitem click listener go to various of screen option but i can't set. i have using model class using added the data from gridview. please help me my issue, i am new in flutter in couple of weeks and here with attached the my code for your reference and please solve to edit my code .

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class GridDashboard extends StatelessWidget {
  Items item1 = new Items(
      title: "Calendar",
      subtitle: "March, Wednesday",
      event: "3 Events",
      img: "assets/calendar.png");

  Items item2 = new Items(
    title: "Groceries",
    subtitle: "Bocali, Apple",
    event: "4 Items",
    img: "assets/food.png",
  );
  Items item3 = new Items(
    title: "Locations",
    subtitle: "Lucy Mao going to Office",
    event: "",
    img: "assets/map.png",
  );
  Items item4 = new Items(
    title: "Activity",
    subtitle: "Rose favirited your Post",
    event: "",
    img: "assets/festival.png",
  );
  Items item5 = new Items(
    title: "To do",
    subtitle: "Homework, Design",
    event: "4 Items",
    img: "assets/todo.png",
  );
  Items item6 = new Items(
    title: "Settings",
    subtitle: "",
    event: "2 Items",
    img: "assets/setting.png",
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Items> myList = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6];
    var color = 0xff453658;
    return Flexible(
      child: GridView.count(
        childAspectRatio: 1.0,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 18,
        mainAxisSpacing: 18,
        children: myList.map((data) {
          return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(color),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset(data.img, width: 42),
                SizedBox(height: 14),
                Text(
                  data.title,
                  style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 8),
                Text(
                  data.subtitle,
                  style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white38,
                      fontSize: 10,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 14),
                Text(
                  data.event,
                  style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white70,
                      fontSize: 11,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Items {
  String title;
  String subtitle;
  String event;
  String img;
  Items({this.title, this.subtitle, this.event, this.img});
}
```

Comment: you need a `GestureDetector` or `InkWell` widgets - more here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation

Comment: how to add and which place of add. i am new in flutter just 3 weeks only. please edit my code please.

Comment: check [Gestures](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook#gestures) (and the whole `cookbook` as well)

Comment: That's ok dude. but my code is different . which place i set?

Comment: ok dude i wil check

Comment: i am try but not working.

Comment: Place an inkwell on the container that is returned by gridview and write the Navigation function in onTap, and you can use if/else or switch or you can add page number in items object on which you want to navigate to and direct accordingly. You can create a dynamic page so you can just pass the name of the item as parameters when you send the user to the next page and the next page will be rendered according to whatever item you have passed.

Comment: To make it easier to understand, what @pskink is trying to say is this: ```myList.map((data) {
          return GestureDetector( onTap:()=>Navigator.of(context).push(...), child: Container());}``` Learn https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics and fill in the `...` inside  Navigator.of(context).push

Comment: not working.i want set gridview index(item click).

Comment: please help me anyone?